# Gauss quadrature rule with a specific weighting function

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials

I am wondering if anyone can point me to a Gauss quadrature rule on $[0,\infty)$ with $w(x)=x^2\ \mathrm{exp}(-x^2)$. The most similar thing that I can find is the one that is based on the generalized Laguerre polynomial with a weighting function $w(x)=x^a\ \mathrm{exp}(-x)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Laguerre-GaussQuadrature.html). Thanks!

Comment: Should be this Shizgal, B. (1981). A Gaussian quadrature procedure for use in the solution of the Boltzmann equation and related problems. Journal of Computational Physics 41, 309–328, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(81)90099-1

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Would you be interested in an algorithm for creating such quadrature rules?  There is not just a single Gauss quadrature rule with given weight and interval $[0,\infty)$, but rather a family of rules of varying orders of accuracy.

Comment: @hardmath I think the paper that slitvinov does provide a set of formula to calculate rules for any order of accuracy, for p = 0, 1, 2. However if you know of a more general algorithm please share with us : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shizgal, B. (1981). A Gaussian quadrature procedure for use in the solution of the Boltzmann equation and related problems. Journal of Computational Physics 41, 309–328 [doi:10.1016/0021-9991(81)90099-1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(81)90099-1)

> A new Gaussian quadrature procedure is developed for integrals of the
>   form $\int_0^\infty \, e^{-y^2} y^p F(y) \, dy $ for $p$ = $0$, $1$ and $2$. Recursion relations are
>   derived for the coefficients in the general three term recurrence
>   relation for the polynomials whose roots are the quadrature abscissae.
>   A comparison with the Gauss-Laguerre quadrature procedure is
>   presented. Solutions of the chemical kinetic Boltzmann equation are
>   obtained with a discrete ordinate method based on this Gaussian
>   quadrature procedure. The results are compared with previous solutions
>   obtained with a polynomial expansion method.